# Which package to install to get header file glad.h?

Tags: software-installation, c++, opengl

I am trying to compile this example https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
// ...
```

I have installed `libglfw3-dev` but I am still missing the `glad.h` header file. A search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=glad.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=disco&arch=any) gave no results. There is a [github page](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad) for `glad` but it does not provide `glad.h` as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm not sure to be able to help but it seems you have to use the web service https://glad.dav1d.de/ to generate the glad.h file (here some comments from the website you were visiting https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window). I tried it using really random parameters and it generates several files including a glad.h. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @dc37 for the comment on the webservice! Here is what I did: Go to the [webservice](https://glad.dav1d.de/) and download the required files:

---

[image]

---

Check the "local files" option and click on the "Generate" button in the lower right corner,

---

[image]

---

download the `glad.zip` file to the current directory and extract it.

Create a [test program](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window) `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>  
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
            glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();    
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it (remember to install `libglfw3-dev` first):

```
g++ -c glad.c 
g++ test.cpp -o my_test glad.o -lglfw -ldl
```

Run it:

```
$ ./my_test
```

(It shows an empty window on the screen)

Comment: "Glad" to hear that it works ;) Have fun with your glad.h file.